# Strange Exception on DataBind of drop down list

Tags: asp.net, exception

I got an Exception on this code:

```
ddlSalesMgr.SelectedIndex = -1;
ddlSalesMgr.SelectedValue = null;
ddlSalesMgr.DataBind();
```

> Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'ddlSalesMgr' has a SelectedValue
>   which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.

Why did this thing is throwing here? I've set up SelectedValue to null...

Comment: what happen if you remove first two lines??

Comment: Your selection does not exist. Bind the dropdown first. Also indexing starts from 0 and SelectedValue is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ddlSalesMgr.DataBind();
ddlSalesMgr.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

You can't select index -1 because it starts at 0

Answer (score 0):

You can not use SelectedIndex=-1. Bare in mind ddlSalesMgr.Items.Add will add a new Listitem element at the bottom if you call it after performing a DataSource/DataBind call so use ddlSalesMgr.Items.Insert method instead eg...

```
ddlSalesMgr.DataSource = DataAccess.GetDropDownItems(); // Psuedo Code
ddlSalesMgr.DataTextField = "Value";
ddlSalesMgr.DataValueField = "Id";
ddlSalesMgr.DataBind();

ddlSalesMgr.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select", ""));
```

Will add the 'Please select' drop down item to the top.

And as mentioned there will always be exactly one Item selected in a drop down (ListBoxes are different I believe), and this defaults to the top one if none are explicitly selected.